# How can I show the changing proportion of binary outcome under different conditions in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, geom-bar

I am trying to generate a graph showing how the percentage of a single outcome changes under a few different conditions.

I am pasting the dput output of a sample data.frame object assigned SampleData:

```
SampleData <- structure(list(Patient = c(7L, 29L, 10L, 6L, 14L, 11L, 28L, 21L, 
5L, 18L, 4L, 1L, 24L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 19L, 3L, 12L, 30L), Symptom_Dur = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("<2.5 Months", ">2.5 Months"), class = "factor"), 
    Outcome = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Better w/ Steroids", 
    "Needed Surgery"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Specifically, I am trying to generate a plot that shows the percentage of patients who needed surgery when they had symptoms for less than 2.5 months versus the percentage of patients who needed surgery when they had symptoms for greater than 2.5 months. (I may look at different time point in the future too).

I have tried making a bar graph using x = Outcome and faceting by symptom duration as below but I cannot get a graph that excludes the bins for "Better w/ Steroids":

```
SampleData %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Outcome, y = stat(prop), group = 1)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Symptom_Dur)
```

I am looking to get something similar to the plot below:

[image]

Note that the above image only shows the percentage of patients who `Needed Surgery`. I am trying to avoid a graph that has data for **both** the `Better w/ Steroids` and the `Needed Surgery` patients.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your desired plot, use `x = Symptom_Dur` instead of `x = Outcome` and remove the `facet_wrap` part. Then just edit labs and add title.

```
SampleData %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Symptom_Dur , y = stat(prop), group = 1)) +
  ggtitle( "Percentage of patients needing surgery based on symptom duration")
```

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid you are calculating the proportion of people in  each `Symptom_Dur` level, not the proportions of people within a `Sympton_Dur` category that also need surgery.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach by making the other group transparent.

```
ggplot(SampleData) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Symptom_Dur, fill = Outcome), position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("transparent", "black"),
                    guide = "none")
```

[image]